# scrollToEnd in Android - GraphView

Tags: android, android-graphview

I'm trying to use [Android - GraphView](http://www.android-graphview.org/). Specifically I'm using the [real time chart](http://www.android-graphview.org/realtime-chart/). Now out of the two options available to update a graph, I want to use the [resetData](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/series/BaseSeries.html#resetData-E:A-). And I want after plotting of graph, my graph should scroll to the very end of it.

If I had been using the other option of [appendData](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/series/BaseSeries.html#appendData-E-boolean-int-), I had to just set the `scrollToEnd` variable to `true` in the parameter list of `appendData`. But I want to use the first option (`resetData`), and the graph should scroll.

Although, there isn't anything in their documentation for the same. But I'm just curious if that is possible, if I tweak their code a little?

Comment: You want to your graph to move to left. right ?

Comment: The `viewport` should move to right.